# Access to Firebase Storage in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm fairly new to Flutter and haven't ever used Firebase before so my aplogies if there is an obvious solution to this.

I'm working on a Flutter app which involves recording form submissions and submitting them to a central location.

Firebase Storage seemed like a good fit since as I understood it the app can upload files to the cloud bucket and then they can be accessed through the Firebase console. Correct me if I'm wrong.

So I found this module for Flutter;
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_storage

I used the example code as a basis.

once at the start of the code I call;

```
final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
  name: 'test',
  options: new FirebaseOptions(
    googleAppID: Platform.isIOS
        ? '{ios app id}'
        : '{android app ID}',
    gcmSenderID: '{project number code}',
    apiKey: '{web api key from the firebase console}',
    projectID: '{project ID}',
  ),
);
storage = new FirebaseStorage(
    app: app, storageBucket: '{address to data bucket}');
```

Then to upload a file I've tried;

```
final StorageReference ref =
storage.ref().child('uploads').child(filename);
final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(
  file,
  new StorageMetadata(
    contentLanguage: 'en',
    customMetadata: <String, String>{'activity': 'submission'},
  ),
);


final Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;

final http.Response downloadData = await http.get(downloadUrl);
final String name = await ref.getName();
final String bucket = await ref.getBucket();
final String path = await ref.getPath();


return downloadData.statusCode >= 200 && 299 >= downloadData.statusCode;
```

and in the Firebase console I created the Uploads folder and I think set everything else up correctly.

My Firebase storage access rules look like this;

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is that when I try to upload the file I get the following error;

```
W/DynamiteModule(25832): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage not found.
I/DynamiteModule(25832): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:6
I/DynamiteModule(25832): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage, version >= 6
W/System  (25832): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000040/n/armeabi-v7a
W/System  (25832): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000040/n/armeabi
E/StorageUtil(25832): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
W/NetworkRequest(25832): no auth token for request
E/StorageException(25832): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(25832): User does not have permission to access this object.
E/StorageException(25832):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException(25832): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(25832): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzs(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzr(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzl(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.zzq.run(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
E/StorageException(25832):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
E/StorageException(25832):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/StorageException(25832): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
E/StorageException(25832):  at bha.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685022@12.6.85 (040308-197041431):147)
E/StorageException(25832):  at bha.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685022@12.6.85 (040308-197041431):119)
E/StorageException(25832):  at bgu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685022@12.6.85 (040308-197041431):7)
E/StorageException(25832):  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zza.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzm.zzf(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzq.zza(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzc(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  ... 6 more
E/StorageException(25832): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(25832): User does not have permission to access this object.
E/StorageException(25832):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException(25832): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(25832): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzs(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzr(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzl(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.zzq.run(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
E/StorageException(25832):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
E/StorageException(25832):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/StorageException(25832): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
E/StorageException(25832):  at bha.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685022@12.6.85 (040308-197041431):147)
E/StorageException(25832):  at bha.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685022@12.6.85 (040308-197041431):119)
E/StorageException(25832):  at bgu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685022@12.6.85 (040308-197041431):7)
E/StorageException(25832):  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zza.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzm.zzf(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzq.zza(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzc(Unknown Source)
E/StorageException(25832):  ... 6 more
```

Is it possible to log in with an app account (service account?) so individual users do not need to log in?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I guess what you are missing is https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth. If you run in an Android emulator, ensure it's one with Play Store installed.

Comment: "Play Store" should be "Google Play services"

Comment: Yeah I should have mentioned that I'd already added this package to see if it was required, before that the error included a reference to it before the other messages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Quoting* from your *`StorageException`*:

> User does not have permission to access this object.

This is what you would expect because your **rules** state the following:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

*Firebase* uses authentication.

There are *two options* to solve this:

- Either you *authenticate* your users with *Firebase* using the ***[`firebase_auth`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth) plugin***
- Or you make your files publicly available by changing your rules to `allow read, write;`

The [Storage Rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security) contains information about integrating **Firebase Authentication**.

Comment: yeah that is what I thought, however even when I set the access to storage to public I the same error. is there a delay when updating access rules?

Comment: @peopletookallthegoodnames I do not think so. You might be missing something.

Comment: Yeah it looks like there was a slight delay with the rules propagating, so when I tried again later with public access everything worked as expected!
Thank you