# Firebase StorageException has occurred kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, storage

I trying to upload a Image to firestore when I registering as a new user. but I get following message:

"Please sign in before trying to get a token."
"StorageException has occurred."

Here is my code:

private fun registerUser() {

```
    imageButton?.isEnabled = false
    var photoDownloadUrl: String? = null
    val photoUploadUri = URI as Uri

    val photoreference = storageRef.child("profileimages/-photo.jpg")
    photoreference.putFile(photoUploadUri)
    photoreference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { photoUploadTask ->
        photoDownloadUrl = photoUploadTask.toString()


        if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !name.isEmpty()) {
            mAuth?.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val user = mAuth?.currentUser
                        val uid = user!!.uid
                        //name = newUsername?.username.toString()
                        val username = User(name, photoDownloadUrl!!)

                        //val nuser = mapOf((newUsername?.username) to name)
                        //firestoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                        firestoreDB.collection("users").document(uid).set(username)
                        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Successfully registered :)",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Error registering, try again later :(",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill up the Credentials :|", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
        println(name)
    }
}
```

Here is my rules in my database:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50905259/8956604

Comment: After I try that code I thought it work, but It doesn't. but it works fine whit "allow read, write;". Cause as you now this code says that if you have a user it's fine. But in this stage I don't have any user. Do you have clue? @KasımÖzdemir

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#understand_rules